# hide everything within a div including background image

Tags: html, css

I have a div with some contents. I am able to hide the contents in the div with css visibility attribute. The css visibility attribute only hides the content and does not hide background image of base64. My challenge now is to hide everything with the div including the base64 background image. Here is the attempt

```html
<div class="stl_02a">
   <div class="stl_03a">
//this is the background image
    <img src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAzAAAAQgCAYAAAA5ebkOAAAAAXNSR0IArs4c6QAAAARnQU1BAACxjwv8YQUAAAAJcEhZcwAADsMAAA7DAcdvqGQAABGuSURBVHhe7dshjh1kGIXhkciRyEoUYQmzDCRLQLACFDtAdgfYBjUK2aBIcATRNIjK6vLfzBCSq+ee9PvO8yQnM7muyZfp/zbTOwAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAF7Mz2ePZmZmZmaDR5Gvzh7MzMzMzAYPAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAgEkezz6ZhXe5OwAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAADo8erswewz3+VO4Rb8DLSJ8zMRqPb67NHsM9/lTuEW/Ay0ifMzEQAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA4D/3Z6+evl1h258H4KV88/wVbsmdkeLWir09+2RmZmZmNmw/nlHou7PXT9+usO3PA/ASHs4en76Fm/rrzG9CkODWigkYgP0EDCkelaS4tWICBmA/AUOKRyUpbq2YgAHYT8CQ4lFJilsrJmAA9hMwpHhUkuLWigkYgP0EDCkelaS4tWICBmA/AUOKRyUpbq2YgAHYT8CQ4lFJilsrJmAA9hMwpHhUkuLWigkYgP0EDCkelaS4tWICBmA/AUOKRyUpbq2YgAHYT8CQ4lFJilsrJmAA9hMwpHhUkuLWigkYgP0EDCkelaS4tWICBmA/AUOKRyUpbq2YgAHYT8CQ4lFJilsrJmAA9hMwpHhUkuLWigkYgP0EDCkelaS4tWICBmA/AUOKRyUpbq2YgAHYT8CQ4lFJilsrJmAA9hMwpHhUkuLWigkYgP0EDCkelaS4tWICBmA/AUOKRyUpbq2YgAHYT8CQ4lFJilsrJmAA9hMwpHhUkuLWigkYgP0EDCkelaS4tWICBmA/AUOKRyUpbq2YgAHYT8CQ4lFJilsrJmAA9hMwpHhUkuLWigkYgP0EDCkelaS4tWICBmA/AUOKRyUpbq2YgAHYT8CQ4lFJilsrJmAA9hMwpHhUkuLWigkYgP0EDCkelaS4tWICBmA/AUOKRyUpbq2YgAHYT8CQ4lFJilsrJmAA9hMwpHhUkuLWigkYgP0EDCkelaS4tWICBmA/AUOKRyUpbq2YgAHYT8CQ4lFJilsrJmAA9hMwpHhUkuLWigkYgP0EDCkelaS4tWICBmA/AUOKRyUpbq2YgAHYT8CQ4lFJilsrJmAA9hMwpHhUkuLWigkYgP0EDCkelaS4tWICBmA/AUOKRyUpbq2YgAHYT8CQ4lFJilsrJmAA9hMwpHhUkuLWigkYgP0EDCkelaS4tWICBmA/AUOKRyUpbq2YgAHYT8CQ4lFJilsrJmAA9hMwpHhUkuLWigkYgP0EDCkelaS4tWICBmA/AUOKRyUpbq2YgAHYT8CQ4lFJilsrJmAA9hMwpHhUkuLWigkYgP0EDCkelaS4tWICBmA/AUOKRyUpbq2YgAHYT8CQ4lFJilsrdnnw/3J2+cttw346e3P1mZlZ+74/+/3qM7Nb7P3Zt1efmd1if58JmFKXgPnz7PIvcxv2x9m7q8/MzNr39uzD1Wdmt9jHs9+uPjO7xf45EzClNv7K1f3zVwD+52cjCe6MFL9CVsz/GQEAYBoBU0zAAAAwjYApJmAAAJhGwBQTMAAATCNgigkYAACmETDFBAwAANMImGICBgCAaQRMMQEDAMA0AqaYgAEAYBoBU0zAAAAwjYApJmAAAJhGwBQTMAAATCNgigkYAACmETDFBAwAANMImGICBgCAaQRMMQEDAMA0AqaYgAEAYBoBU0zAAAAwjYApJmAAAJhGwBQTMAAATCNgigkYAACmETDFBAwAANMImGICBgCAaQRMMQEDAMA0AqaYgAEAYBoBU0zAAAAwjYApJmAAAJhGwBQTMAAATCNgigkYAACmETDFBAwAANMImGICBgCAaQRMMQEDAMA0AqaYgAEAYBoBU0zAAAAwjYApJmAAAJhGwBQTMAAATCNgigkYAACmETDFBAwAANMImGICBgCAaQRMMQEDAMA0AqaYgAEAYBoBU0zAAAAwjYApJmAAAJhGwBQTMAAATCNgigkYAACmETDFBAwAANMImGICBgCAaQRMMQEDAMA0AqaYgAEAYBoBU0zAAAAwjYApJmAAAJhGwBQTMAAATCNgigkYAACmETDFBAwAANMImGICBgCAaQRMMQEDAMA0AqaYgAEAYBoBU0zAAAAwjYApJmAAAJhGwBQTMAAATCNgigkYAACmETDFBAwAANMImGICBgCAaQRMsR/O3pw9mJmZmZkN2fuzr88o9OvZu7NHMzMzM7Mh+3h2+Yd4Cn1xdv/0LQAAjPDl81cAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA2ODu7l9MWGjRg3gQ4wAAAABJRU5ErkJggg==" alt="" 
    class="stl_04a">
   </div>
   <div class="stl_view">
    <div style="visibility:collapse; background: #fff">
      //..... content here and to hide everything within this div
    </div>
</div>
</div>
```

how to hide everything within the above div is the challenge

Comment: Can you make an example with the image? As `display:none;` does the job in this case.

Comment: I have editted the question to show bg image

Comment: You have to put the `display:none;` to the div with class: `stl_02a'. Then everything from that class will be hidden (including the image).

Comment: there are content in in stl_02a that I want to remain visible

Comment: Then add `display:none` to the image. :)

Comment: are u saying I cannot hide display of a div and everything with the domain of the div

Comment: Yes you can so you can also `display:none;` the `ltl_03a` div. But that div is outside the div you've put the visibility on.

Answer (score 0):

instead of `visibility:collapse`, use the `display:none` property.

Also, reading from [this](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_visibility.asp) page, `visibility:collapse` is only for table rows, row groups, columns, column groups. This value removes a row or column, but it does not affect the table layout. The space taken up by the row or column will be available for other content.

If you want to use it on other type of elements, `visibility:hidden` should be used.

**EDIT:**

Now that you edited your post, it's obvious why your "background" image shows, and that is because the element with the content and the element with the background image are unrelated. You need to set `display:none` or `visibility:hidden` on the div with class `stl_02a`

Comment: the background image still shows but the content does not

Comment: @user10445503 display: none should hide the entire div including background.

Comment: @user10445503 show us all your relevant code (include your background-image)please

Comment: are you sure you are setting the `visibility` property on the element where the background is, instead of a child element of it?

Comment: it is a child element more reason why I want to hide everything within the div irrespective whether a child element or not

Comment: there are contents in the div that I want to be displayed